# New feature when clicking on the vote count

Tags: discussion

I just accidentally clicked on the vote count instead of the up-vote icon, and lo and behold, I get a breakdown of the votes (how many up and how many down).

Is this a new feature, or has it just not been very discoverable up until now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an old feature and comes in at 1,000 reputation on graduated sites and [750 reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) on beta sites.

Comment: If i did not read the privileges page, i would have never discovered it.